# Bad return type in lamba expression

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am getting the following compilation error with the given code -

> Bad return type in lamba expression: Map < String, Set< Param>> can
>   not be converted to Map < String, List< Map< String, Object>>>

I have no clues at all why this error. As mapToReturn and dummyMap are of same type.

```
    Map<String, Set<Param>> mapToReturn = Optional.ofNullable(CACHE.get(content, (key) -> {
        hit.set(false);
        Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> rawMap = Paser.parse(Map.class, key);
        Map<String, Set<Param>>  dummyMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> entry : rawMap.entrySet()) {
            dummyMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .map(this::mapToParam)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
        }

        return dummyMap;
    })).orElseThrow(() -> new ParamParserException("... "));
```

Comment: `Param` == `Parameter` ?

Comment: yea. corrected that. Sorry that was a typo

Comment: What are the method signatures of `CACHE.get` and `Paser.parse`, and what is the type of `content`? Also, you misspelled "Parser".

Comment: @Douglas .. signatures of CACHE.get and Parser.parse do not really matter. I have changed the code to remove them

Comment: I'm fairly certain they do matter, and are the reason for your issue. I would not have asked otherwise. Please add them anyway. If you have changed your local code in a way that proves me wrong, then post the new code.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `CACHE.get` certainly matters and this is the reason for which you are getting this error. I tried to reproduce the problem. Consider the relevant to your question part of the code:

```
Map<String, Set<Param>> aMap = Optional.ofNullable(CACHE.get(content, (key) -> {
            //...
            Map<String, Set<Param>>  dummyMap = new HashMap<>();
            //...
            return dummyMap;
        })).orElseThrow(() -> new ParamParserException("... "));
```

This code will compile, if the signature of `CACHE.get` is the following:

```
static class CACHE 
{
    static Map<String, Set<Param>> get(String content, Function<String, Map<String, Set<Param>>> func)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Now let's change the signature:

```
static class CACHE
{
   static Map<String, Set<Param>> get(String content, Function<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>> func)
    {
         return ...;
    }
 }
```

This fails with the following error:

> bad return type in lambda expression `Map<String,Set<Param>>` cannot be
>   converted to `Map<String,List<Map<String,Object>>>`

Which is exactly the error which you are getting. The signature of `Paser.parse` is not the reason because the error message would have been different.

Comment: I'm not so sure about `Parser.parse` being irrelevant. It could be involved in a chain of generic inferences.

Comment: Of course `Parser.parse` is relevant. But if there was a problem with its signature the error message would be different. The error which the OP quoted is about the *return type* of the lambda which means that the compiler complains about `dummyMap`.

Comment: `Parser.parse` could be part the problem even so. I suspect that both `CACHE.get` and `Parser.parse` are generic, and that generic inference is going from the type of `rawMap` -> the inferred signature of `Parser.parse` -> the inferred type of `key` -> the inferred signature of `CACHE.get` -> the inferred expected return type of the lambda -> error because `dummyMap` doesn't match. Otherwise, it seems quite a coincidence that the inferred return type of the lambda exactly matches `rawMap`.